# Remote To other Computers

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I Have a Computer with Windows 7 in my Office Network.I want Remote to Other Computers And I don't want Use Windows Remote Desktop.I want a Software for Remote without Need to Client Software on Destination Computers.

Please Help me ...

Comment: Looks like spy work :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your requirements, I don't think it can be done.  You want to:

1. Remote from your Windows PC
2. Connect to a client PC
3. Not using Remote desktop
4. Not use any other software

**Numbers 3 and 4 are mutually exclusive.**  If you don't install anything, you have to use Remote Desktop since it is what is installed by default in Windows.  If you don't want to use RDP, you have to install something.

Comment: I want Install a Remote Software just in My Computer...

Comment: You need to have something to connect to.  If you don't install anything extra at the target computer, you MUST use RDP.

Comment: This could not be more correct.  There's no way around it - if you want to spy on other people's computers you're going to have to install something.  Yes, this means they might figure it out.  (Pardon my projection but I can't think of any other reason for this restriction...)

Answer (score 1):

It could just be me but the question seems backward. If you are connecting remotely then in my mind the destination would need a host not a client.
On the off chance that you do want remote access, are willing to use a host software, and don't want to install a client on every computer that accesses it...
Most VNC based solutions offer using a browser as the client
http://www.realvnc.com/support/javavncviewer.html

If you really don't want an installed host, then sorry.